# Opening url using raster package in R

Tags: r, raster

I am novice in R. I have a below url, and I want to open it using the raster package:

```
m<-http://abc.amazonaws.com/thredds/dodsC/abc/2017092600/mnc
```

I tried to open it using the raster package:

```
 library(raster)

file<- raster(m)
```

But I got the below error:

```
 Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
                                   Cannot create RasterLayer object from this file; perhaps you need to install rgdal first
```

Then, I tried installing rgdal package using

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

But I got the below error:

```
Installing package into ‘D://Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cloudyr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  cannot open URL 'http://cloudyr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
try
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the first glance, it seems that the file `m` does not exist on that url.

Comment: @Geo-sp, m file do exist on that url.

Comment: You need to use `download.file(m,file_name,mode='wb')` and after this use `file <- raster(file_name)`

Comment: @aldo_tapia, thanks for reply. But I am still getting error: cannot open url "....": HTTP status bad request.

Comment: the file does not exist on that url (what is the extension?), put the _working_ url between quotes: `m <- 'http://UrlToFile.extension'`, and follow @aldo_tapia 's comment above